# Issue with Fragment lifecycle: getView() is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a `MainActivity`, with a layout including two `FrameLayout` to load `Fragments`, one for a top bar with a vertical menu, another one for the content.

Everything works properly, excepted when I click the device's Home button and start the app again.

For instance when I start the app, click the menu option 2, which replaces the content fragment by an instance of the `SomeFragment` shown below, then click the device's Home button, then start the app again, it restarts the `SomeFragment` `Fragment` as expected, but my app crashes in the `TopBarFragment`, returning an error because the `getView()` is null.

I guess I'm messing with the `Fragment` lifecycle, but I can't find the solution.

Note: in order to test my app I checked the option `Don't keep activities` in my device's developer options.

Anybody can help?

**EDIT**

When restarting the app, `onResume` is not called in the `TopBarFragment` instance. Why?
The instance called by

```
((TopBarFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentByTag("top_bar_fragment")).setSelectedButton(1);
```

seems to be 'empty'... Why?

**EDIT 2: more experiments**

When clicking on the device's Home button, `onDetach` and `onDestroyView` are called in `TopBarFragment`, so why is `onCreateView` not called again when restarting the app?

**EDIT 3: more experiments**

When restarting the app, the `MainActivity` `onCreate` is called, so

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, homeFragment, "");
```

is executed. However, it loads `SomeFragment`, which is nice because it was the last `Fragment` loaded in the `content_container`, but unexpected because `MainActivity` `onCreate` is called and it should load `HomeFragment`...

**stacktrace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.package/com.my.package.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.my.package.TopBarFragment.setSelectedButton(TopBarFragment.java:345)
    at com.my.package.SomeFragment.onCreateView(SomeFragment.java:50)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1861)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4480)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1940)
    ... 11 more
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

        setContentView(R.layout.main);      

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        Fragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, homeFragment, "");

        Fragment topBarFragment = new TopBarFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.top_bar_container, topBarFragment, "top_bar_fragment");

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="44dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**TopBarFragment.java**

```
public class TopBarFragment extends Fragment{   

    private int mSelectedMenuOption = 0;

    private LinearLayout mVerticalMenu;

    private Boolean mMenuIsOpen = true;

    private ImageButton btn_01, btn_02; // there are more


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_bar, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        btn_01 = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_01);
        btn_02 = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_02);

        btn_01.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);
        btn_02.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);

        mVerticalMenu = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.vertical_menu);

        toggleMenu(0);

        Button btn_menu = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_menu);
        btn_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // toggle vertical menu             

            }
        });
    }


    private OnClickListener mButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            /* ... */

            if(!v.isSelected()){

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                switch(v.getId()){

                case R.id.btn_01:

                    Fragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();     
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container,homeFragment, "");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    break;

                case R.id.btn_02:

                    Fragment someFragment = new SomeFragment();     
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, someFragment, "");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    break;      
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void setSelectedButton(int i){

        // Crashes when starting the app, clicking on btn_02 to load a SomeFragment instance, clicking on the 
        // device's Home button, and starting the app again: getView() is null
        // why?

        /* ... */            

        mSelectedMenuOption = i;
    }
}
```

**SomeFragment**

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ((TopBarFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("top_bar_fragment")).setSelectedButton(1);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the stacktrace with the exception?

Comment: Keep in mind that you create a new instance of those fragments each time the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method gets called. When that happens it appears that trying to call `setSelectedButton(1)`(where you work with the fragment's views?!) on the TopBarFragments is done when its view isn't yet built. Try to move the `TopBarFragment` replacement transaction before the content fragment transaction(I would do this part with an activity callback system instead of letting the fragments needing to communicate between them(and on top in their `onCreateView` methods)).

Comment: Wow. You're right. If I move the `TopBarFragment` transaction before the content fragment transaction, I get the `HomeFragment` when I restart the app, which is good. What I still don't get is why is `SomeFragment` `onCreateView` still called when restarting the app, while `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, addFragmentToStack(homeFragment), "");` is executed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last question. The `onCreateView()` call is normal if the fragment is getting built. Also, as I already said, your current code will create duplicates if the Activity gets recreated(and `onCreate()` is called again).

Comment: What I do not understand is why is a `SomeFragment` instance recreated if the `MainActivity` is supposed to create a `HomeFragment` when restarting the app?

Comment: Are you doing anything special in the addFragmentToStack method?

Comment: It's just a stack for when the user press the back button. `    public Fragment addFragmentToStack(Fragment fragment){
  if(fragmentStack.size()>STACK_SIZE){
   fragmentStack.remove(0);
  }
  return fragmentStack.push(fragment);
 }`. I'll remove it from the code in the question.

Comment: Are you sure you TopBarFragment doesn't somehow intervene and changes the fragment added as the content?

Comment: It does in the `mButtonClickListener`: if I click on `btn_02` for instance, it loads a `SomeFragment` instance: `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, someFragment, "");`

Comment: @Luksprog: if you put you upvoted comment as an answer I'll accept it, because it actually solves the inital question (the null getView()). I'll ask a new question about the "why is the SomeFragment still loaded" stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stacktrace posted it seems that calling the `setSelectedButton(1)` method on the `TopBarFragment`(where you most likely update/work with its views) is done before its content view is built. Move the `TopBarFragment` replace transaction before the transaction to replace the content view so its view its built before the content fragment try to access it.

Comment: Thanks. Just in case you're interested, my new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16316802/326849;

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in the correct order according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), `onActivityCreated` is after `onCreateView`. I know I have seen lots of working examples on SO where users use `getView()`, but I have always used `getActivity()` instead and put my declarations in my `onStart` and it always works fine for me. You could try the following code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    btn_01 = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_01);
    btn_02 = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_02);

    btn_01.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);
    btn_02.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);

    mVerticalMenu = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vertical_menu);

    toggleMenu(0);

    Button btn_menu = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_menu);
    btn_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // toggle vertical menu             

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't see why it would change anything. When onActivityCreated is called, getView() is not null, so the view members btn_01, mVerticalMenu... are properly set. When the app is stopped and restarted, onActivityCreated is not called again anyway. Whatever I tried, the view has disappeared.

Comment: *but I have always used getActivity() instead* - that is one way to get some bugs if you end up using the same fragment class multiple times in the same activity.