# Destroyed fragment recreated and redestroyed when restarting the app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I'm trying do understand the lifecycle of `Fragment`.

I have a `MainActivity`, with a layout including two `FrameLayout` to load `Fragments`, one for a top bar with a vertical menu, another one for the content.

When I start the app, an instance of `HomeFragment` is loaded in the content `FrameLayout` container. Then when I click on a button in the menu, an instance of `SomeFragment` replaces it.

When on the `SomeFragment` content, I click on the device's Home button, and all the visible `Fragment` (i.e. the `TopBarFragment` and the `SomeFragment`) are destroyed and detached from the `MainActivity`, i.e. `onDestroyView`, `onDestroy` and `onDetach` are called for both.

Now when I restart the app, the `TopBarFragment` and the `SomeFragment` are created and destroyed (full lifecycle from `onAttach` to `onDetach`) and then the `TopBarFragment` and the `HomeFragment` are created, as expected from the code in the `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`.

Why are the `TopBarFragment` and the `SomeFragment`, i.e. the latest visible `Fragment` before clicking on the device's Home button, recreated and destroyed before executing what's in the `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`?

Note: in order to test my app I checked the option `Don't keep activities` in my device's developer options.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

        setContentView(R.layout.main);      

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        Fragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, homeFragment, "");

        Fragment topBarFragment = new TopBarFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.top_bar_container, topBarFragment, "top_bar_fragment");

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="44dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**TopBarFragment.java**

```
public class TopBarFragment extends Fragment{   

    private int mSelectedMenuOption = 0;

    private LinearLayout mVerticalMenu;

    private Boolean mMenuIsOpen = true;

    private ImageButton btn_01, btn_02; // there are more


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_bar, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        btn_01 = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_01);
        btn_02 = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_02);

        btn_01.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);
        btn_02.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);

        mVerticalMenu = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.vertical_menu);

        toggleMenu(0);

        Button btn_menu = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_menu);
        btn_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // toggle vertical menu             

            }
        });
    }


    private OnClickListener mButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            /* ... */

            if(!v.isSelected()){

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                switch(v.getId()){

                case R.id.btn_01:

                    Fragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();     
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container,homeFragment, "");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    break;

                case R.id.btn_02:

                    Fragment someFragment = new SomeFragment();     
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, someFragment, "");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    break;      
                }
            }
        }
    };    
}
```

**SomeFragment**

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ((TopBarFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("top_bar_fragment")).setSelectedButton(1);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't the `Don't keep activities` option supposed to simulate an `Activity` that goes to the background and it gets killed there due to memory constraints? If this is the case(and I run a simple test) then the behavior you see its quite normal as the `FragmentManager` of the `Activity`(the Activity needs to restore its state) will still have references(and will try to bring those fragments to life) to the old instances present when the activity ended up in the background.

Comment: Ok, so even if they are killed, the whole lifecycle is done just because of a reference to them? Isn't it useless?

Comment: It's not just a reference, the Activity gets destroyed in the background but the state is saved(including the fragments) so the activity could recreate itself(along with the last stored fragments).